# PostresSQL - Оператор ilike и много %

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица в базе данных и в этой таблице есть атрибут s_name (тип text)

Значение этого атрибута в одной из строк ↓

Поиск технологии с влиянием на рычаг "Увеличение накопленной добычи" не менее, чем на 3% по направлению Органическая химия область Повышение эффективности ГРП и освоения скважин (ожидаемый образ результата - Оборудования и установки, год готовности технологии - 2022, текущий УРТ - TRL1+)

Есть запрос в эту бд

```
SELECT s_name FROM challenge
where s_name ilike 'рычаг %увеличение накопленной% добычи не менее% чем на 3% по направлению органическая химия область повышение эффективности грп и освоения скважин %ожидаемый образ результата % оборудования и установки% год готовности технологии % 2022% текущий урт % trl1%%';
```

Не понимаю почему данный запрос для выше описанного значения атрибута не выдаёт совпадений?
Каким образом бд аккумулирует разные части строки если они заключены в % ?
Гугление на эту тему результатов особо не дало, 95% это примеры использования ilike\like с % в единичном варианте

Однако заметил если изменить данный запрос на такой (добавить 2 знака % - один перед первым словом "рычаг" и второй после 4-го слова "добычи"), то запрос выводит совпадение и отрабатывает
Буду благодарен за любой совет

```
SELECT s_name FROM challenge
where s_name ilike '%рычаг %увеличение накопленной% добычи% не менее% чем на 3% по направлению органическая химия область повышение эффективности грп и освоения скважин %ожидаемый образ результата % оборудования и установки% год готовности технологии % 2022% текущий урт % trl1%%';
```

Comment: @Akina не помогает

Comment: `%` заменяет любое количество любых символов. Остальные символы ищутся как есть, причем с самого начала строки, поэтому если в начале нет `%` то искомая строка в БД должна начинаться на те символы которые у вас в выражении, т.е. на "рычаг". Но у вас строка в БД не начинается на "рычаг" вот и не находится

Comment: *Не понимаю почему данный запрос для выше описанного значения атрибута не выдаёт совпадений?* В значении между словами "добычи" и "не менее" - двойная кавычка и пробел. В шаблоне - только пробел. Плюс написанное выше.

Comment: @Mike 
Тогда следуя этому при добавлении % в начале в запросе перед словом рычаг, всё должно работать но всё равно не работает, только если добавить одновременно и перед словом рычаг и после слова добычи

Comment: @Akina, Mike
Спасибо, всё понял!